# Help with proving an algebraic equation $(x-y) - (z-w) = (x+w) - y - z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I have decided to work on my math foundations and began working through "Basic Mathematics" by Serge Lang. I am currently working on the first set of exercises and I know this is probably really basic for most people, but I am having a hard time with proving this equation using associativity and commutativity:

$$(x-y) - (z-w) = (x+w) - y - z$$

My trouble is that if I am working to prove the right side of the equation is equivalent to the left, I am not sure how to turn the 'w' to a negative. I am guessing it has to do with its additive inverse but can't figure how to get at it. Can anyone give me any hints in proving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To what properties of real numbers have you been presented?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia do you mean associativity and commutativity? That is what is what I has been presented thus far.

Comment: Are you working on the reals or on the integers?

Comment: I am working with integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given
\begin{align*}
(x-y) - (z-w)\\
\text{the distributive law of multiplication yields}\\
(x-y) - z+w\\
\text{the associative and commutatative laws of add/subratct yield}\\
(x+w)-y-z
\end{align*}

Comment: @coffeemath
 I fat fingered and got signs reversed. I have fixed it.

Comment: OK deleting comment.

Comment: Okay! I did some research last night and found that the distributive law of multiplication allows me to flip the signs of -(z-w), which turns into +(-z+w)... however, Lang's book presents the problem before the law, so I was stuck for a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The set of integer numbers $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined as equivalence classes of pair of natural numbers.

More precisely, given two integers $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $(c,d)\in\mathbb{Z}$, we say that

$$(a,b)\sim(c,d) \Longleftrightarrow a + d = b + c$$

Moreover, we can also define addition as $(a,b) + (c,d) := (a + c, b + d)$.

And finally we define the inverse additive of $(a,b)$ as $-(a,b) := (b,a)$.

Based on such considerations, we can approach the proposed problem.

Let $x = (x_{1},x_{2})$, $y = (y_{1},y_{2})$, $w = (w_{1},w_{2})$ and $z = (z_{1},z_{2})$. Then the LHS can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
x - y - (z - w) & = (x_{1},x_{2}) - (y_{1},y_{2}) - ((z_{1},z_{2}) - (w_{1},w_{2}))\\\\
& = (x_{1},x_{2}) + (y_{2},y_{1}) - ((z_{1},z_{2}) + (w_{2},w_{1}))\\\\
& = (x_{1} + y_{2}, x_{2} + y_{1}) - (z_{1} + w_{2},z_{2} + w_{1})\\\\
& = (x_{1} + y_{2}, x_{2} + y_{1}) + (z_{2} + w_{1},z_{1} + w_{2})\\\\
& = (x_{1} + y_{2} + z_{2} + w_{1}, x_{2} + y_{1} + z_{1} + w_{2})\\\\
& = ((x_{1} + w_{1}) + (y_{2} + z_{2}), (x_{2} + w_{2}) + (y_{1} + z_{1}))\\\\
& = (x_{1} + w_{1}, x_{2} + w_{2}) + (y_{2} + z_{2},y_{1} + z_{1})\\\\
& = (x_{1}, x_{2}) + (w_{1}, w_{2}) + (y_{2},y_{1}) + (z_{2}, z_{1})\\\\
& = (x_{1}, x_{2}) + (w_{1}, w_{2}) - (y_{1},y_{2}) - (z_{1}, z_{2})\\\\
& = (x + w) - y - z
\end{align*}

which is exaclty the RHS.

Comment: This, although it follows the usual method for constructing the integers, may be a bit over the OP's head.

Comment: @coffeemath I have questioned him if it is supposed to be solved in the context of real numbers. Whether it is the case, I am going to edit it my solution.

Comment: It was a bit over my head but I still appreciate the answer because I know what ∈Z and ⟺ means now lol.